# Adding a constructor to an injected Project Class

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to add a constructor, which I call `ctor`, to [`Project`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/), so I can add to it some properties when it's instantiated.

Here's the (absolutely ghastly) hack I'm using on [`Item`](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/) to make this tick:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
paper.setup(canvas)

paper.Item.inject({
  ctor: function(args) {
    console.log('Item constructed!')
  }
})

// All Items are supposed to call `_initialize` so we "hook" there.
const Item_initialize = paper.Item.prototype._initialize
const Item_ctor = paper.Item.prototype.ctor

paper.Item.prototype._initialize = function(...args) {
  const initializer = Item_initialize.apply(this, args)
  if (Item_ctor) Item_ctor.apply(this)

  return initializer
}

const path = new paper.Path.Line({
  strokeColor: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  from: 100,
  to: 50
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-core.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Unfortunately the above trick doesn't work on `Project`:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
paper.setup(canvas)

paper.Project.inject({
  ctor: function(args) {
    // Not called
    console.log('Project constructed!')
  }
})

const Project_initialize = paper.Project.prototype._initialize
const Project_ctor = paper.Project.prototype.ctor

paper.Project.prototype._initialize = function(...args) {
  const initializer = Project_initialize.apply(this, args)
  if (Project_ctor) Project_ctor.apply(this)

  return initializer
}

const project = new paper.Project(canvas)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-core.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your hack doesn't work on Project class because it doesn't have any `_initialize()` method so even if you add one, it will never be called. Look at the source code: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/item/Project.js

Comment: @sasensi Yeah I'm going through the source code again and unfortunately you're right. Any ideas on how to make this tick? Short of modifying the source code myself I see no viable alternative.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Maybe there is a better approach to find ?

Comment: @sasensi I'm working on a large project where I do extensive subclassing + modifying the PaperJS classes themselves. I want to add some properties on every instance of `Project` for example. I don't want to do this externally to keep my API neat and tidy when I actually instantiate those classes. For example, every `Item` in my project has an `UndoManager` which I set using the trick explained in my question. I'd like to do something similar in `Project` as well.

Comment: The easiest way that I see and that I have used in one of my project is to extend the classes. You can look at the `Layer` class [code](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/item/Layer.js) which extends the `Group` class to have an example of how it could be done.

Comment: @sasensi AFAIK If I `extend` the class paperJS won't use my extended `Project` when importing/exporting. At least, judging from the source code, it won't. Instead it would use the default `Project` class. That's the reason I'm insisting on `inject` but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: No, in that case, I guess that you would have to export/import from your class instead and overload these methods to do what you want. But anyway, your case seems to be very specific so I think that you are the best placed to find the solution.

Comment: @sasensi At this point, modifying [straps](https://github.com/lehni/straps.js) itself so it calls a custom `ctor` on all classes and building my own version of the library seems like a better alternative. I really wanted to avoid that but  I don't see any other "clean" way.